# how to detect MSword is opened with specific file?

Tags: c#

I want to open word file from my Windows Application in C#.
On button button click i called Process.start() with file name say "Test.doc".
File name vary according to some situation.

Now as many times i click the button Process started with same file it started many instance of word.

i want it should open a single instance for same file, and if file name changes then only open new instance.

So how can i detect that word is opened with some file name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list that keeps tracks of Processes that are running. So:

```
List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
```

When you click to open the file:
a) make sure the list does NOT contain a process with your filename. (traverse the list then look at process.Filename and compare it to the file you're wanting to open)
b) if it doesn't, add your process to the list and then just start the process.

Then use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx

To know if the process has exited. When it ends, get rid of it from your process list.

Comment: I want to close all the opened instances of word now from Form closed event.

I iterate all processes and kill them but when i next time open the same file in word it shows some recovery option.
anyway thanks

Comment: i got it how to close the process.

Comment: cool man, yeah i didn't think there was much you could do as word might not like being closed by someone else but i guess you got it!